# Split numpy array based on arbitrary values contained in it

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, split

I’d like to split this (numpy) array:

`[ 4 0 1 3 2 3 8 10 11 4 12 13 15 14 4 16 18 19 17 4 20 21 23 22]`

into something like this:

`[[0 1 3 2] [8 10 11] [12 13 15 14] [16 18 19 17] [20 21 23 22]]`

The first number `4`, indicates how many subsequent numbers I need to group `[0, 1, 3, 2]`, the next one would be `3`, so the next values to group would be `[8, 10, 11]`, and so on.

Is there an efficient way to do this? I need to handle arrays that will have thousands or hundreds of thousands of values.

Thanks!

Comment: No, (2D) numpy arrays have to be quadratic.

Comment: where is your code ? What did you try?

Comment: It could be converted to a regular list, it doesn't necessarily have to be a numpy array
@furas I have no code, I'm not sure how to approach the problem

Comment: It seems you fogot `2` after `4, 0, 1, 3` in first list.

Comment: you're right, I missed the 2, thanks for editing it. I'm going to try out your answer and I'll report back. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if numpy has something for your problem.

This is simple solution but probably for big list it may not be so efficient

```
data = [4, 0, 1, 3, 2, 3, 8, 10, 11, 4, 12, 13, 15, 14, 4, 16, 18, 19, 17, 4, 20, 21, 23, 22]

results = []

while data:
    number = data.pop(0)
    results.append(data[:number])
    data = data[number:]

print(results)
```

Result:

```
[[0, 1, 3, 2], [8, 10, 11], [12, 13, 15, 14], [16, 18, 19, 17], [20, 21, 23, 22]]
```

---

**BTW:** maybe using indexes (with less slicing data) can be faster.

```
data = [4, 0, 1, 3, 2, 3, 8, 10, 11, 4, 12, 13, 15, 14, 4, 16, 18, 19, 17, 4, 20, 21, 23, 22]

results = []
index = 0
length = len(data)

while index < length:
    number = data[index]
    index += 1
    results.append(data[index:index+number])
    index += number

print(results)
```

---

**EDIT:** second version works also with numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.asarray([4, 0, 1, 3, 2, 3, 8, 10, 11, 4, 12, 13, 15, 14, 4, 16, 18, 19, 17, 4, 20, 21, 23, 22])

results = []
index = 0
length = len(data)

while index < length:
    number = data[index]
    index += 1
    results.append(data[index:index+number])
    index += number

results = np.asarray(results)
print(results)
```

Result:

```
[array([0, 1, 3, 2]) array([ 8, 10, 11]) array([12, 13, 15, 14]) array([16, 18, 19, 17]) array([20, 21, 23, 22])]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this using list comprehension

```
lst = [4, 0, 1, 3, 3, 8, 10, 11, 4, 12, 13, 15, 14, 4, 16, 18, 19, 17, 4, 20, 21, 23, 22]

marker = lst[0]

split_array = [[lst[x] for x in range(c, c+marker) if x < len(lst)] for c in range(1,len(lst),marker)]

>>> split_array
[[0, 1, 3, 3], [8, 10, 11, 4], [12, 13, 15, 14], [4, 16, 18, 19], [17, 4, 20, 21], [23, 22]]
```

Comment: this gives wrong results. splited data may have different sizess - and you have to get other "markers" for list. BTW: OP forgot `2` after `4, 0, 1, 3`.